# Stripe connected calls from the Front End, change the Stripe connected ID programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to solve this proble that I cant seem to solve with stripe's API's

So when creating a charge with their new version API they say that in the front end we should call loadStripe('Pusblishable Key',{'Connected account ID'}) and set that to a const.

now I dont undestand how are we supposed to get the ID that is stored somewhere say a database?

As a reference please look at [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#add-stripejs-and-elements-to-your-page) and [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) (In Step 3 ...).

What I'm currently doing is something like this

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
        import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

        import CheckoutForm from './CheckoutForm';

      //btw I have set this to const and to let and none work
        const stripePromise =
          fetch("url", {


              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                anything:window.sessionStorage.getItem("Variable Account")
    //here store something that  will tell what account to pull ID data from
              })
            }).then(data => data.json()).then((result)=>{
              return(loadStripe('KEY',{stripeAccount:result}))

            })

class App extends React.Component{
render(){
return(
     <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <CheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
)}
}

export default(App)
```

but the const seems to not load correctly, if one goes with the regular flow of the app say from 
myapp.com/home -> click myapp.com/home/something-> then myapp.com/home/something/payment stripe is not loading but one refreshes the browser now works but that tells me i'm doing maybe something wrong or I have to make the app refresh in 'componentDidMount()' maybe?

One can set it to be static but connected accounts  can be many so if anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Answered the same as your duplicate question: [How to properly load global variable with async values(Reactjs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589252/how-to-properly-load-global-variable-with-async-valuesreactjs/)

Generally, you'd want to have this account ID available in your app. But if you need to retrieve it, that's fine, but make sure the `stripePromise` is what you think it is. For example, I can make this work here with a simulated fetch call here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stripe-connect-w-resolve-wts34

Note that I'm managing the Promise explicitly:

```
const stripePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(...)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(result => {
    resolve(
      loadStripe(STRIPE_PUBKEY, { stripeAccount: "acct_xxx" })
    );
  });
});
```

The fact that you describe this breaking with navigation suggests you might be routing incorrectly. If this is a single page app, the navigation shouldn't cause the `App` component to re-render.

Comment: Ok so I changed the body from window.sessionStorage to just gather the data from the URL that seems to fix it (seems window.session was the problem,I had this working when I made all static similar to yours well the body was static string then the DB would respond) but when I added the part where it was taking data from the session then it broke down and would only work upon refreshing the page. Now you mentioned that one would want to have this available in the app but where I mean one could potentially have more than one account ID then, would one do like a text parser or something?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to manage that in any framework. With React in particular you could use `state` or one of many state management systems like redux. Basically you'd have some kind of list of accounts, then you'd track which was currently selected in the application state.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a const

```
const stripePromise = const stripePromise = fetch(...
```

It should be

```
const stripePromise = fetch(...
```

This is what I saw at first glance.

Comment: That's a typo sorry