# How to properly load global variable with async values(Reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, stripe-payments

I'm trying to solve this problem that I can't seem to solve with stripe's API's

So when creating a charge with their new version API they say that in the front end we should call

```
loadStripe('publishable Key',{'Connected account ID'})
```

and set that to a const.

now I dont undestand how are we supposed to get the ID that is stored somewhere say a database?

As a reference please look at [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#add-stripejs-and-elements-to-your-page) and [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) (In Step 3 ...).

What I'm currently doing is something like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm";

//btw I have set this to const and to let and none work
const stripePromise = fetch("url", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    anything: window.sessionStorage.getItem("Variable Account")
    //here store something that  will tell what account to pull ID data from
  })
})
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(result => {
    return loadStripe("KEY", { stripeAccount: result });
  });

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <CheckoutForm />
      </Elements>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

but the const seems to not load correctly if one goes with the regular flow of the app say from

```
myapp.com/home
```

-> click

```
myapp.com/home/something
```

-> then

```
myapp.com/home/something/payment
```

stripe is not loading but one refreshes the browser now works but that tells me I'm doing maybe something wrong or I have to make the app refresh in 'componentDidMount()' maybe?

One can set it to be static but connected accounts  can be many so if anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stripe connected calls from the Front End, change the Stripe connected ID programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584572/stripe-connected-calls-from-the-front-end-change-the-stripe-connected-id-progra)

Comment: no that's why I asked it again

Comment: That isn't how this works. You shouldn't repost a question because it isn't answered. You should elaborate on your question to make it clearer for people to give answers and to make it the best possible question. When you update it, it will `bump` it to the top of `active` questions anyway. You can also place a bounty on the question.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this platform so I'll look into placing a bounty thank

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias, have you ever seen anything like this or my approach is incorrect?. I tried to also use this.setState() to load it but it cannot be altered once loaded accourding to a warning thrown by Stripe, they recommed to keep it outside the render of any component.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd want to have this account ID available in your app. But if you need to retrieve it, that's fine, but make sure the `stripePromise` is what you think it is. For example, I can make this work here with a simulated fetch call here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stripe-connect-w-resolve-wts34

Note that I'm managing the Promise explicitly:

```
const stripePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(...)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(result => {
    resolve(
      loadStripe(STRIPE_PUBKEY, { stripeAccount: "acct_xxx" })
    );
  });
});
```

The fact that you describe this breaking with navigation suggests you might be routing incorrectly. If this is a single page app, the navigation shouldn't cause the `App` component to re-render.